# What does "om" in org.apache.axiom.om means?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, axiom

I'm pretty new to Web Services in java. I was starting on a project where one is already implemented, and there are lots of references to org.apache.axiom.om namespace.

What does the om stands for ?

Comment: http://ws.apache.org/axiom/apidocs/org/apache/axiom/om/package-summary.html

Comment: and google answered http://ws.apache.org/axiom/apidocs/org/apache/axiom/om/package-summary.html and given all the text that was given, it really didn't catch my eyes.

Comment: Yeah, the doc link doesn't tell you what "om" stands for.  I Googled and checked several docs and couldn't figure it out.  I figured it was just Apache's mantra.

Comment: @mre -- How do you "infer" that "OM" means "Object Model"??  I would have guessed "Object Management".

Comment: given the context of its use, i inferred "Object Model" given "DOM", which stands for "Document Object Model".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stands for Object Model:

http://ws.apache.org/axiom/apidocs/org/apache/axiom/om/OMXMLBuilderFactory.html

Look under `createOMBuilder()` - the definition is:

Create an **object model** builder that reads a plain XML document from the provided input stream with the default parser configuration defined by StAXParserConfiguration.DEFAULT.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it stands for *Object Model*, since it's written all around everywhere in [Axiom home page](http://ws.apache.org/axiom/), even in the title.

I guess some imagination could be used in this situation..

Comment: I am imaginative, but I write all my namespaces with entire words. Explicit is better than implicit. (Zen of Python).

Comment: @Stephane So I assume someone should tell Guido to rename the `re` package to `regularexpression`? There's also a `weakref`, `sched`, `os` - well I could go on. Sometimes brevity is important too ;)

Comment: yep you are right ;-), and it's is admitted (in the books i have read at least) that the python module names are to much fussy.